# How with a help of id connect family members in a family tree program with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, family-tree

I am working a program in C# in a Visual Studio development, as a base, I am using SQL Server 2016.

My problem is that I can't determine who is related to whom using the ID of each member.

Comment: Hi, could you provide us with some more information? What is the project in question? What is the database schema? Could you clarify your question a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some kind of a `Person` table. You would implement a mapping table storing all the relationships between two persons (and the type of the relationship).

The table could look like this:

```
Id; PersonId; RelatedPersonId; RelationshipType(Id)
```